# Python library to process Portable Game Notation in chess

Tags: python, library, chess

I want to replay chess games in [Portable Game Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_game_notation), which describes moves such as the King's Knight opening with

```
1. e4 e5 2. Nf3
```

I adapted [FlaskChess](https://github.com/brokenloop/FlaskChess) in Python for this purpose and it can take a list of moves such as the equivalent of the King's Knight opening with:

```
e2e4
e7e5
g1f3
```

or it can take the current state of play in [Forsyth-Edwards Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth-Edwards_Notation), which describes the state of the board after the King's Knight opening with:

```
rnbqkbnr/pppp1ppp/8/4p3/4P3/5N2/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKB1R b KQkq - 0 2
```

I am looking for a Python library that converts the moves in Portable Game Notation to either of these to be replayed on a GUI. Does it already exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like [python-chess](https://pypi.org/project/python-chess/) could be what you're looking for, unless I'm missing something. Specifically, [check out the docs related to PGN.](https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/v0.31.2/pgn.html)

Available via pip.

Here is an example for the King's Knight opening:

```
import io

import chess.pgn

pgn = io.StringIO("1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 *")

game = chess.pgn.read_game(pgn)

board = game.board()
for move in game.mainline_moves():
    print(move)
    board.push(move)  # to update and render the board
```

The result is:

```
e2e4
e7e5
g1f3
```