# Replayer of chess moves in PGN or openings

Tags: library, python, chess

I programmed a replayer of chess moves from Portable Game Notation, such as [Milman v Fang, 2005](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caro-Kann#Classical_Variation:_3...dxe4_4.Nxe4_Bf5), with [FlaskChess](https://github.com/brokenloop/FlaskChess) for the server and [python-chess](https://pypi.org/project/python-chess/) for the logic (thanks to [Python library to process Portable Game Notation in chess](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/74946/python-library-to-process-portable-game-notation-in-chess)). I use it to replay games and to visualize openings. Although it's working, alternative game lines (or tree branches) are awkward and I wonder if I am reinventing the wheel.

I'm looking for an existing chess replayer that can take strings in Portable Game Notation such as `1. e4 c6` for the Caro-Kann, display them visually, and nicely represent alternative branches.

Does it already exist?